# Encoding YUV to mP4 With qp to get max quality

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4, h.264, yuv

I am trying to encode my YUV420 Raw format file into mp4. Here is the ffmpeg command

```
ffmpeg -f s16le -ar 44100 -ac 1 -i "0.a" -f rawvideo -pix_fmt yuv420p -s 480x480 -r 30 -i "0.v" -vcodec libx264 -profile:v baseline -preset ultrafast -qp 0 -b:v 1024k -g 30 -acodec libfdk_aac -ar 44100 -ac 1 -b:a 64k -f mp4 -movflags faststart "1438947231095.mp4"
```

If i remove qp = 0; it works however the quality is very low not sure why. If i put qp = 0 it doesn't work, What is wrong?

Getting this error

```
Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The baseline profile doesn't support lossless H.264. You must use the **High 4:4:4 Predictive** profile instead:

`-profile:v high444`

Comment: What is the way to minimize the loss from above

Comment: Use  a low `-crf.` The ffmpeg guide lists 18 as visually lossless, but in your case you can try to go lower.

Comment: i have tried same but the quality is still low. I am using Vitamio to record YUV it may be YUV problem that it is recording in low quality, however if i run that YUV in normal YUV player all i see is rainbow with blurry images. any help there?

Comment: I think you should post another question, maybe add a small sample file.